# how to take a value from an object and turn it to string?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
 public UcCard CardValue()
    {
        UcCard current = pack[index];
        UcCard.Type cardvalue = 0;
        current.Value = cardvalue;
   edit:return current.Value.ToString(cardvalue);
        //////return UcCard.ToString(cardvalue);
    }
```

edit:now it says that it cannot convert the "***.UcCard.Type" to string

im getting the error "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments" 
what im trying to do is take a value from UcCard and then print it, now i know that UcCard is an object, but im not sure on how to take the value and transfer it to string

im new to coding so be gentle T_T i tried searching for an answer before posting but i just couldnt find an answer that fitted my need

also, this is where im trying to take the value from:

```
  public int Volume
    {
        get
        {
            switch (lblValue.Text)
            {
                case "2": return 2;
                case "3": return 3;
                case "4": return 4;
                case "5": return 5;
                case "6": return 6;
                case "7": return 7;
                case "8": return 8;
                case "9": return 9;
                case "10":
                case "K":
                case "Q":
                case "J": return 10;
                case "A": return 1;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "now i know that UcCard is an object" - that is strange. From your sample `UcCard` is type.

Comment: then i was mistaken, or confused, i saw a post somwhere that implicated that it was an object.

Comment: `UcCard` is a type. You need to call `ToString()` on an instance of that type. Try `cardvalue.ToString()`.

Comment: i tried and it said i cant implicitly convert type string to "***.UcCard.Type"

Answer (score 0):

Every class or struct in C# implicitly inherits the Object class. 

This class contains the ToString method which is called when you prints out strings .

And you should customize it for your use AKA override it because the program will not guess what `Attributes` it should print not mention in what format.

(e.g from MSDN )

```
class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }

   public override string ToString()
   {
       return "Person: " + Name + " " + Age;
   }
}
```

Comment: im not really sure on how to implement the override string in my case, if you can elaborate on that it would be really helpful

Comment: well, clean up your thread .
Share the `UcCard` file and i may be able to help u then :)